# LINQ support for generic Lists

Tags: c#, linq

Is there no LINQ support for generic Lists?

```
MyRecord[] array = GetRecords();
List<MyRecord> list = new List<MyRecord>(array);
```

I am unable to do a `list.Select()` Are the linq methods available only on `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`?

Comment: What do you mean you can't do `list.Select()`?

Comment: There even is support for arrays. You should be able to do `array.Select(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work. Make sure you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

in your code file. Since Linq is based on extension methods they won't be automatically resolved for you, so you have to add the `using` statements yourself.

Comment: yep, have made this mistake a number of times

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LINQ is supported against `List<T>` (which *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`, btw). It's called LINQ to Objects. Check that you've:

1. Selected an appropriate framework version (3.0 or above) for your project.
2. Referenced the System.Core.dll assembly.
3. Used the `System.Linq` namespace.